# How to find out which httpd.conf apache is using at runtime

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I've always struggled to find this: How can you ask apache which httpd.conf file it used to load up?

It becomes difficult when you have a number of instances of apache running, or if you haven't looked at the machine for a long time, and there are a lot of httpd.conf file on disk!

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 61):

```
apache2ctl -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE
```

Comment: Bingo. Please note that the binary might be called apachectl for different distributions or operating systems. Also grep for HTTPD_ROOT - the value of HTTPD_ROOT prepended to SERVER_CONFIG_FILE will give you the full path to the config file.

Comment: In my case it's: -D HTTPD_ROOT="/srv/www" 
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"

Comment: This saved my day=) You could also simply try `httpd.conf` in the case that the SERVER_CONFIG_FILE is named something else: `apachectl -V | grep httpd.conf`.

Comment: Might also be httpd -V

Comment: For me the answer worked fine but I had to replace apache2ctl with apachectl.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2016 ([Bug 59376](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59376)), from `Apache 2.4.23` onwards, an option dedicated to this purpose is available.

It can display the entire config file tree, including line numbers, which is useful to debug complex configurations.

```
$ apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES

Included configuration files:
  (*) /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
    (21) /etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk_log.conf
    (21) /etc/httpd/conf.d/healthd.conf
    (21) /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
    (22) /etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf
    (22) /etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01_gzip.conf
    (22) /etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/02_static.conf
```

Or,

```
$ httpd -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

Answer (score 5):

`/usr/sbin/apache2 -V` provides this info and a little more :)

Comment: You could improve this answer by providing some example output of that command.

Answer (score 2):

In Yosemite I found it was
`/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf`

Even though `apachectl -V | grep .conf`

Gives `-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"`

Comment: Passing arguments to httpd using apachectl is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

For RHEL or Centos, first find the running Apache process...

```
ps ax | grep httpd
```

Note the path in the output.  For me, it is...

```
/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd
```

You can then use the -V option with this path to get the configuration path...

```
/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd -V
```

Amongst the output you should see an absolute path for HTTPD_ROOT and also a relative path for the SERVER_CONFIG_FILE.  Put that absolute path and relative path together and you have your configuration file location.

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22900993/861826