# How can I tell which config file Apache is using?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I'm trying to set up virtual hosts on Mac OS X. I've been modifying httpd.conf and restarting the server, but haven't had any luck in getting it to work. Furthermore, I notice that it's not serving files in the DocumentRoot mentioned in httpd.conf (Libraries/WebServer/Documents), but in a different directory (/usr/local/apache2/htdocs). I don't see this folder mentioned anywhere in httpd.conf. Furthermore, PHP works, but the "LoadModule php5_module" line is commented out. This makes me think it's using another .conf file. How can I figure out which config is actually being loaded?

Update: I just deleted that httpd.conf and apache behaves the same after restart, so it definitely wasn't using it!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

With any *nix application, the easiest method is to query the binary itself.  In the case of httpd, I'd imagine the process would be something like this:

```
$ whereis httpd
/usr/sbin/httpd
$ /usr/sbin/httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.11 (Unix)
Server built:   Jun 17 2009 14:55:13
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:21
Server loaded:  APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
Compiled using: APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/private/var/run/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

As you can see - my OS X says the binary, if not directed otherwise, will use the config file: */private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf*

If that doesn't help, perhaps Christopher's suggestion of *find* is the next step.

Comment: This won't work if you're using Apache via the Server.app In that case you'll need the process list in the answer from @msanford http://serverfault.com/a/155114/187798 which shows that the Server.app starts httpd with a different configuration file as shown here from my installation (Mavericks) `/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf -D WEBSERVICE_ON`

Comment: also does not work with when using apache installed via macports -- answer by msandord works for me!

Answer (score 27):

There's another serverfault question regarding [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/12968/how-to-find-out-which-httpd-conf-apache-is-using-at-runtime). If you're using a debian based server you can use `apache2ctl` to determine which config file is being used:

```
apache2ctl -V
```

More on this:

[How to find out which httpd.conf apache is using at runtime](https://serverfault.com/questions/12968/how-to-find-out-which-httpd-conf-apache-is-using-at-runtime)

Comment: On macOS, the command to find out which config files the running instance of https is **actually** using is `apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES`.

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
ps ax | grep httpd
```

and you should (might) get output like

```
1633   ??  Ss     0:00.21 /usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/httpd.conf
```

Additionally, how exactly are you restarting the server? Just curious in case you somehow aren't *actually* re-reading the config file.

Comment: hm it doesn't have the `-f` flag in it

Comment: +1 As this is the only answer that works for all cases, that is if you're configuring Apache yourself or if you're using Apache via Server.app

Comment: It doesn't work for me, may due to my current error conf....

Answer (score 4):

Because some configs use Server app, brew or whatever, and because one liners FTW :

```
$(ps ax -o comm | grep -m 1 httpd) -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE
```

This command do the following :

- Find an active httpd process
- Output config info
- Grep the config file

Tested on Sierra & El Capitan

Comment: The `$` is important (it's not the command line prompt in this case). If converts the statement in parens into a command, to which we pass the `-V` flag. Leaving it out results in: "syntax error near unexpected token `-V'".

Answer (score 0):

First, check which is the startup script for Apache. For macOS, it should be /Library/LaunchDaemons. That might include a working directory, or similar information.

You could also debug the running process itself with dtruss. You can connect to the running process using `dtruss -p <pid>`. Then, if you HUP it, you can probably pore over the output to see where it's grabbing its config from.  Alternately, just start Apache by calling dtruss directly with `dtruss start_apache_command`.

You could always just do a system-wide search for httpd.conf with `find / -name httpd.conf`.