# Apache want port 80 without binding it to this port

Tags: apache-2.4, centos6

When I want to start my apache server, it shows me this error:

> Starting httpd:
>
> (98) Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
>
> (98) Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>
> no listening sockets available, shutting
>   down Unable to open logs
>
> [FAILED]

My **httpd.conf** file:

```
Listen 8181
```

As you can see, I have deleted everything else. Still, Apache wants to bind to port 80 which is used by varnish. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Have you verified that the httpd.conf file you edited is [the httpd.conf file apache is using](http://serverfault.com/questions/12968/how-to-find-out-which-httpd-conf-apache-is-using-at-runtime)?

Comment: @DiogenesdeLight Yes. Before deleting the rest of file, I got the list of all included files and checked them for any possible mis-configurations. But no luck.

Comment: What I mean is something different. If you follow the link I posted, you'll see there are various ways to get apache to tell you the path to its config file. Whenever I change a config file, get no errors, and the behavior is unaffected, I like to make sure the file I edited is really the file that the program is using as its config file. I think it's worth checking that, esp. with apache.

Comment: Apache does not have a default for Listen, so it must be defined somewhere, look deeper and better.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to rule out:

- Apache is using another config file than the one you expect.

Do the following:

1. Kill whichever httpd process you have running
2. Start Apache in foreground with explicit conf file **/sbin/httpd -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf -DFOREGROUND**

Second thing:

- Check which other config files are loaded by your httpd.conf

  grep Include /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
- Find out which of the loaded config files that have Listen directives defined.

  grep -r Listen /etc/httpd/

Some *Listen* directive somewhere must be hiding from you.

Comment: I should've deleted this question because problem was installing two instance of apache on the same server (one compiled in custom directory, the other using yum) . There was a conflict between them!